# Ionic 2 *ngFor not refreshing by promise in promise (in promise)

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngfor

i'm trying to load some messages in my Ionic 2 app, and store them in a SqLite db to avoid downloading them several times.

So basically i ask my Sqlite the last ID saved, then ask the server all the messages newer than that ID, then fill the board with the saved messages until i reach 20 messages (with a single call obviously).

So the technical part: i'm putting all these messages in an array, that should be shown in the App with an *ngFor. When i run the app on the PC, it shows correctly (so the logic is correct), but when i run the app on the Phone it's like if the *ngFor doesn't get refreshed and the messages are not shown.

Not always, by the way. If i unload the page i see for a moment the messages (the array is finally shown in the *ngFor), and if i load it again it shows them (not because now they are saved, but because they are already in some cache i think).

The answer is: there is a limit to the *ngFor that i'm missing? How can i let the message show ALWAYS? I already lowed down the messages limit from 100 to 20, but it didn't solve the problem.

Here is the code, with the three promises:

getMessages(){
    this.dbService.getLastMessageId().then((data) => {

```
  let lastId = 0;     
  if (data.res.rows.length > 0)
    lastId= data.res.rows.item(0).Id;


    this.http.get(URL+lastId)
      .subscribe(data => {

      var response = data.json();
      let newMessagesCount = response[0].count;
      for (let i =1; i<=newMessagesCount; i++)
        this.messages.push(response[i]);

      if (newMessagesCount <20)
        this.dbService.getOldChatMessages(20-newMessagesCount).then((data) => { 

      if (data.res.rows.length > 0){
        let rowsCount = data.res.rows.length;
        for (let i=0; i<rowsCount;i++){
          let newElement = {
            Name: data.res.rows.item(i).Name,
            Date: data.res.rows.item(i).mexDate,
            Text: data.res.rows.item(i).mexText,
            Id: data.res.rows.item(i).Id,
            New: 0
            };
          this.messages.push(newElement);

          }                
      }
     //HERE I EXPECT THE ARRAY TO BE READY
      if(newMessagesCount>0){
        this.dbService.storeNewChatMessages(response);                    
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your for loops in a zone like this:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

export class MyPage {
  zone: NgZone;

  constructor() {
    this.zone = new NgZone({enableLongStackTrace: false});
  }

  getMessages() {

    this.zone.run(() => {
      for (let i =1; i<=newMessagesCount; i++) {
        this.messages.push(response[i]);
      }
    });

    this.zone.run(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
        let newElement = {
          Name: data.res.rows.item(i).Name,
          Date: data.res.rows.item(i).mexDate,
          Text: data.res.rows.item(i).mexText,
          Id: data.res.rows.item(i).Id,
          New: 0
        };

        this.messages.push(newElement);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. With your suggestion, now on the pc works as it did before, but on my Android device it doesn't enter in that page anymore (the method is called once when the app enters in that page)

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using? And are there any js errors when running on the device and opening the page?

Comment: Ionic 2 rc.3, and i can't see the js errors on the device

Comment: You can access the js console of your android device by going to `chrome://inspect/` in chrome

Comment: I didn't know of this possibility. By the way i can see the device and see if i open Chrome, but while i'm in my app on the device, the console just says "No browsers detected."